# /nfs: read-only file system. | Truenas | VM | DOCKER

Tags: docker, docker-compose, scale, nfs, portainer

I have a server with Truenas scale in it. I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/truenas-scale-ultimate-home-setup-incl-tailscale/186444).

The concept goes within this lines:
Server: Truenas Scale, vm(ubuntu server) in truenas, docker inside the vm.

The goal is to create docker containers in the vm but use the nfs shared folders to save the data from the containers. Al thought the process is intimidating with a number of nonsense here and there, i manage to deploy the nfs and the vm and make the vm to "talk" to the host machine(truenas) following the guide above.

**Truenas**:
ip: 192.168.2.144
user:docker(1000)
group:docker(1000)
pool:main
datasheet:docker-vm
shared-path: ":/mnt/main/docker-vm/docker"

**VM(Ubuntu):**
ip:192.168.2.143
uid:docker(1000)
gid:docker(1000)

The proces to mount the shared path to the VM is:

```
$ sudo mkdir /nfs
$ sudo mount 192.168.2.144:/mnt/main/docker-vm/docker
$ sudo touch /nfs/hello_world      // Output: Permission denied.
```

To solve this problem we have to do the next step:
After that you have to go to the true nas UI and add the user "docker" as Maproot User  and the group "docker" as Maproot Group and the host ip(in this case 192.168.2.143) to the UNIX (NFS) Shares.

After that i am able to:

```
$ touch /nfs/hello_world
$ ls /nfs         //Output : -rw-rw-rw- 1 docker docker 0 Oct  9 12:36 helo_wold
```

The next step is to create the Portainer container and store the files in the nfs:

```
$ mkdir /nsf/portainer_data

$ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9443:9443 --name portainer --restart=always -v 
  /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /nfs/portainer_data:/data    
  portainer/portainer-ce:latest
```

The docker run command return this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path 
'/nfs/portainer_data': mkdir /nfs: read-only file system.
```

I am frustrated cuz i am able to create files and folders to the /nfs  as user but the docker can't? I hope i covered the problem enough and someone can help me.

Comment: System administration questions are generally better suited to [unix.se]; Stack Overflow's scope is narrowly focused on questions about _writing code_.

Comment: (that said, "read-only filesystem" is supposed to be given only when the filesystem itself is mounted with the `ro` flag, not when the filesystem is read-write but permissions don't allow a given user to perform the desired operation; that said, Docker itself can and does set up a new filesystem namespace, and can mark things read-only inside it).